# Understanding data flow from mxd to map service?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, map-service

In my project I publish map, feature and dynamic services. My task is :

1. Add tables or views from Oracle 12c DB to ArcMap, then assign symbology and scale.
2. Prepare and save final MXD, then publish it as map, feature and dynamic service.

Until now I understood that the data source of a map service is a MXD, and MXD has a database (.sde) connection. But sometimes the database connection of MXD gets broken and red exclamation appears against layers. But if I execute a query in REST service URL then I do see increased record counts than previous record count. Now if MXD database is broken then how are new records appearing through REST URL query? I think I am missing something here in back end process.

Comment: It used to be that server connection failure caused service failure until restart, but modern releases of ArcGIS Server (which doesn't include 10.2 or even 10.3 at this point) handle connection failure gracefully by attempting reconnection.

Comment: Vince, thanks for your inputs, I did some research and found, its TNS connection string on ArcGIS servers and Configuration Store which keep hitting the database and fetch records.